# Get all Custom Post Types

Tags: theme-development, metabox

I am creating a WP theme with a built in custom post type (and I am using WPAlchemy to add a couple of custom metaboxes).

```
$theme_custom_metabox = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(
  array(
    'id' => 'my_metabox',
    'title' => 'Custom Metabox',
    'context' => 'normal',
    'autosave' => TRUE,
    'types' => array('post', 'page', 'theme_custom_post_type'), // Can I add all custom_post_types by default here?
    'priority' => 'high',
    'mode' => WPALCHEMY_MODE_EXTRACT,
    'template' => MY_PATH . '/includes/my_theme/metaboxes/my_metabox.php',
));
```

Reason: 'Out of the box', WPAlchemny requires you to list the post_types in the 'types' array - this works fine if you know all the `post_types` being used, but this is a theme to be shipped so the actual CPTs being used would be unknown.

I would like the theme to programmatically add its metaboxes to any custom_post_types the user would add.

I guess the most logical way would be to store all CPTs in a variable. eg:

```
$all_cpt = all_custom_post_keys();

...
'types' => $all_cpt,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

### Easy list filtering

There's the `global $wp_post_types` which is used for e.g. in [`get_post_type_object( $name );`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5eb5afac3450f2bd02886f5f1f4fe56ed208fd79/wp-includes/post.php#L1153), [`register_post_type()`](http://queryposts.com/function/register_post_type/), etc.

If you want to omit the ones delivered with core, you should filter the returned list and skip everything that has the `_builtin` key set to `true`. Just use [`wp_list_filter()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_list_filter/) for that

```
$cpts = wp_list_filter( $GLOBALS['wp_post_types'], array( '_builtin' => false, ) );
```

### Runtime collection

A different way to go at this: At the end of the post type registration (`register_post_type()`) process, there's an action running:

```
do_action( 'registered_post_type', $post_type, $args );
```

This action maybe is - depending on your use case - a nice place to fetch all post types, as core registers its own post types using [`create_initial_post_types()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5eb5afac3450f2bd02886f5f1f4fe56ed208fd79/wp-includes/post.php#L19) which uses `register_post_type()` by itself. It will also allow you to fetch post types that get registered late.

```
add_action( 'registered_post_type', function( $pt, $args )
{
    static $cpts = array();

    if (
        ! $args->_builtin 
        and ! in_array( $args->name, array_keys( $cpts ) ) 
    )
        $cpts[ $args->name ] = $args;

    // here, $cpts gets constant updates as soon as a new post type is registered
    // ignores already added post types by name
    // also ignores cores `_builtin` post types

}, 20, 2 );
```